# PythonAnywhere error didnt had this proble when api was on my local machine

Tags: python

I deployed my api and get this it was working on my local machine

```
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @    react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback    @    react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError    @    react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch    @    react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder    @    react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue    @    react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins    @    react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous)    @    react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1    @    react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates    @    react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem    @    react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Network Tab:

Open your browser's developer tools.
Go to the Network tab.
Check if there are any failed requests when your React app is trying to communicate with the PythonAnywhere API. Look for red entries in the Network tab.
Check the Console for Errors:

Open your browser's developer tools.
Go to the Console tab.
Look for any error messages or warnings related to your React app or API calls.
Check CORS Configuration:

If your React app and PythonAnywhere API are hosted on different domains, ensure that Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is configured correctly on the server-side (PythonAnywhere). This could be causing issues with API requests from the React app.
Check API Endpoint:

Make sure that the API endpoint in your React app is correctly configured to point to the PythonAnywhere API.
Debugging in Production:

If the issue is only happening in the production environment, consider using tools like Sentry or other error tracking services to get more detailed error reports.
Update Dependencies:

Ensure that your React app and PythonAnywhere server are using compatible and up-to-date versions of libraries and dependencies.
Logging:

Add logging statements to your PythonAnywhere API code to log information about incoming requests, any errors, and the responses sent back.